How do I tell xmllint to ignore 'entity' errors
I'm using xmllint as part of the linter settings in ALE (Asynchronous Lint Engine, plugin for Vim). The codebase I'm working on has a lot of HTML entities in XML. Not good, I know, but they're not harming anyone at the moment. So I'd like xmllint to not remind me everytime I open or save a file.
This is what xmllint says:
page.xml:54: parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined
    <Element label="&nbsp;" value="{__t.Delete}" action="{#delete}"/>
                          ^

Is there any way of telling xmllint (directly, or via ALE) to not give me entity errors?

Would using the html parser xmllint --html help?

Just tried that, but that's not working.

If you haven't found anything in $ man xmllint, then you won't find it here.

As a workaround, the --recover option could be added. The document will be parsed provided that no other errors appear but missing entities will be removed.
Given
<root>
  <Data>
    <colA>def&nbsp;</colA>
  </Data>
</root>

Result from xmllint --recover tmp2.xml
tmp2.xml:5: parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined
    <colA>def&nbsp;</colA>
                   ^
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Data>
    <colA>def</colA>
  </Data>
</root>

WARNING: entities will be lost if document is saved
